# Getting a full time work permit in Canada after a language school?

Tags: working-visas, canada, education, working

What are chances to get a full-time work permit (read work visa) after a completing a year-long English language courses program at VGC in Vancouver.

If to be more specific, I'm planning a trip, a long one, and Canada is my first stop. So, my main priority is to improve my English skills and move on, but in a case I want to stay a little longer and continue my education there, I would need money to support myself. Incidentally, I already have the Specialist Degree (which is very close to Master Degree) in Applied Computer Science which I got in Saint Petersburg, Russia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/study/work-postgrad-who.asp) gives all the information about who can apply for a post grad work permit (PGWP).

In general, it depends. If you are doing a program from a sketchy college, CIC just might reject your application and not issue a work permit at all. CIC takes all factors into consideration while issuing a work permit. These factors include but are not limited to:

- The reputation of the college you studied from.
- The similarities of the program you studied back home and the program you studied in Canada.
- You must have successfully met the requirements of the program that you are in. CIC will ask for a confirmation from the college and/or graduation certificate.
- Your program must be a minimum of 8 months.

I want to point out to the second point and explain further that the program you have in mind is an English program and the program you studied back home are not related at all. CIC just might reject your study permit in the first place. So I would advice you to be careful while applying for the study permit. In the past I have seen cases where CIC rejected study permits on the basis of that and also rejected work permits or shrinked the duration of work permits to what is originally applied for.

Also I would advice you to be careful while selecting the college. There are some very sketchy colleges in Canada. Some of them are not even approved or are illegally running just so they can get students. I don't know the reputation of the college that you have mentioned but I would definitely advice you to be careful while selecting it. What I would recommend is talk to a consultant (You don't have to necessarily apply through the consultant) and see what works out best for you.

Good Luck with your trip.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41126/discussion-on-answer-by-dipen-shah-getting-a-full-time-work-permit-in-canada-aft).